# Как вывести количество комментариев в цикле WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Как вывести количество комментариев в цикле WordPress? Вот пример кода, который выводит никнейм автора поста, может можно как то по аналогии вывести количество комментариев?

```
?php foreach ($post_loop as $post): ?>
<?php if (count($post_loop) > 0): ?>
<?php the_author_meta('nickname',$post['author_id']);?>
```

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_comments_number

Comment: @KAGGDesign я читала эту статью, но к сожалению не хватает навыков php, что бы собрать правильно функцию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [wp_count_comments()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_count_comments/), которая принимает в качестве аргумента id записи, количество комментариев которой необходимо получить. Будет что-то [вроде](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_count_comments):

```
<?php
$comments_count = wp_count_comments($post['ID']);
echo "На модерации: " . $comments_count->moderated . "<br />"; 
echo "Утвержденные: " . $comments_count->approved . "<br />";
echo "Помеченные как спам: " . $comments_count->spam . "<br />";
echo "Комментов в корзине: " . $comments_count->trash . "<br />";
echo "Всего комментариев: " . $comments_count->total_comments . "<br />";
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Попробовала ваш код, но к сожалению выдало ошибку: На сайте возникла критическая ошибка.
Узнайте больше про отладку в WordPress.

Comment: Не видел ответа, ляпнул свой коммент с телефона. Плюсанул)

Comment: @Анна попробуйте уточнённый вариант, функция возвращает объект с несколькими значениями. Выбирайте то, что вам нужно

Comment: @KAGGDesign да я там сначала вообще натупила, хорошо что не видел :DD

Comment: @alenkins оно мне выводит общее количество комментариев со всех записей сайта (

Comment: @Анна значит вы не передали в функцию ID поста. Что у вас в $post['ID']?

Comment: @alenkins все сделала, вы были правы. Спасибо